# use Bio::seq not working in Perl

Tags: perl, cpan, bioperl

I installed CPAN and then successfully installed Bioperl. 
I cannot find Bio perl folder in `/usr/bin`

However, the files are present at `home/.cpan/build/BioPerl-1.61/Bio/`

I am unable to use Bio::SeqIO on `Komodo`

IDE: Komodo Edit 8

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Perl -v: 5.14

How should I proceed?

Comment: You may well have installed the libs to your homedir instead of system-wide.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth ohhh, how do I change it now? :(

Comment: Should I add that folder to path?

Comment: I think you need to get some foundational comprehension in place before pursuing this question on SO. http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html -- that's a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The `cpan` command can tell you were something is installed:

```
    $ cpan -D Mojo::UserAgent
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.53)
Reading '/Users/brian/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 18 Feb 2016 12:41:02 GMT
Mojo::UserAgent
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20150520)
(no description)
    S/SR/SRI/Mojolicious-6.46.tar.gz
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Mojo/UserAgent.pm
    Installed: undef
    CPAN:      undef  up to date
    Sebastian Riedel (KRAIH)
    kraih@cpan.org
```

Once you find that directory, ensure that it's in your `@INC` module search path. You can see what the default is with `perl -V`.